# JavaScript not resizing height of UL element sometimes when inserting LI elements using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, height

I have an Html/JavaScript application that contains N columns that need to be large enough contain all of the possible LI elements from all of the columns.

The simple solution seems to count the heights of all of the items in each column, compensate for padding, and then set the height to that total for each of the columns.

This works great when the LI elements contain plain text. Unfortunately, when the LI elements contain images instead, various browsers have problems. For example, when I first load the page in FireFox, it looks like the screenshot below, but upon another refresh, it works fine. It doesn't work as expected in Chrome either.

[image: Screenshot Showing the height of the UL element is not in sync with the LI elements]

My application does not pre-populate the LI elements when the page loads - it uses JavaScript, as follows:

```
function populateUnsetAnswers(unsetCategoryAnswers) {
    for (i in unsetCategoryAnswers) {
        if (unsetCategoryAnswers.hasOwnProperty(i.toString())) {
            $('#categoryQuestionArea #possibleAnswers').append(
                categoryAnswerLiTag(unsetCategoryAnswers[i])
            );
        }
    }
}

function categoryAnswerLiTag(unsetCategoryAnswer) {
    var html = '<li id="' + unsetCategoryAnswer.id + '">';

    if (unsetCategoryAnswer.image) {
        html += '<img class="categoryAnswerImage" title="';
        html += unsetCategoryAnswer.text;
        html += '" src="/trainingdividend/rest/streaming/';
        html += unsetCategoryAnswer.image.fileName;
        html += '" style="height: ';
        html += unsetCategoryAnswer.image.height;
        html += ';';
        html += '" />';
    } else {
        html += unsetCategoryAnswer.text
    }

    html += '</li>';

    return html;
}
```

When the page is done loading, an ajax request fetches all of the objects to be put into LI elements, and then calls the first function above.

After all of the LI elements are created, I call this function right after it:

```
function resize() {
    var currentHeight, totalHeight;
    totalHeight = 0;

    $("#categoryQuestionArea ul").children().each(function() {
        currentHeight = $(this).height();

        totalHeight += currentHeight + 13;
    });

    $("#categoryQuestionArea ul").height(totalHeight);
    $("#categoryQuestionArea div#separator").css("padding-top", (totalHeight / 2) + "px");
}
```

Is there any way to tell jQuery, "Don't call resize() until all of the LI's are fully loaded and the images have rendered" ?

I think what's happening is that on the initial page load, the height of these LI elements is 0 or a small value because it doesn't contain the image, so my resize function is calculating the wrong result (I tested this with some alert statements). As long as the LIs are populated and the images have loaded, the total height is calculated just fine.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you calling the `resize()` function? From what I can see here, you can just call it at the end of `populateUnsetAnswers()` and `JavaScript` will do the resize just right.

Comment: @KemalFadillah Yes, resize() is called just after populateUnsetAnswers() already. This works in firefox only when you do a page refresh. It still doesn't work at all in Chrome.

Comment: @FireEmblem you don't need to set a height at all, the columns will expand vertically to fit the content.

Comment: Do you a demo of this somewhere we can see live? like jsfiddle

Comment: Please could you edit your question, adding the full code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) or a demo (perhaps on [http://jsfiddle.net/](jsFiddle)). It is really difficult to reach a solution without the full problem. See that most of the answers already given are actually guesses!

Comment: Hey, so this may seem strange, but is your UL set to display:block;width:00px;height:00px;position:relative; ? If not give it a try, and see if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

To literally answer the question you asked, if you want to only call `resize()` when all images have finished loading, then you need to install `onload` handlers for those images and when you've recorded that the last one is now loaded, you can call the `resize()` function.  You could do that like this (code explanation below):

```
var remainingAnswerImages = 0;

function categoryAnswerImageLoadHandler() {
    --remainingAnswerImages;
    if (remainingAnswerImages === 0) {
        resize();
    }
}

function populateUnsetAnswers(unsetCategoryAnswers) {
    // add one extra to the image count so we won't have any chance 
    // at getting to zero  before loading all the images
    ++remainingAnswerImages;
    var possibleAnswers$ = $('#categoryQuestionArea #possibleAnswers');
    for (i in unsetCategoryAnswers) {
        if (unsetCategoryAnswers.hasOwnProperty(i.toString())) {
            possibleAnswers$.append(categoryAnswerLiTag(unsetCategoryAnswers[i]));
        }
    }
    // remove the one extra
    --remainingAnswerImages;
    // if we hit zero on the count, then there either were no images 
    // or all of them loaded immediately from the cache
    // if the count isn't zero here, then the 
    // categoryAnswerImageLoadHandler() function will detect when it does hit zero
    if (remainingAnswerImages === 0) {
        resize();
    }
}

function categoryAnswerLiTag(unsetCategoryAnswer) {
    var obj = document.createElement("li");
    obj.id = unsetCategoryAnswer.id;

    if (unsetCategoryAnswer.image) {
        // count this image
        ++remainingAnswerImages;
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = img.onerror = img.onabort = categoryAnswerImageLoadHandler;
        img.title = unsetCategoryAnswer.text;
        img.style.height = unsetCategoryAnswer.image.height;
        img.src = "/trainingdividend/rest/streaming/" + unsetCategoryAnswer.image.fileName;
        obj.appendChild(img);
    } else {
        obj.innerHTML = unsetCategoryAnswer.text;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

By way of explanation, this code makes the following changes:

- Add a variable `remainingAnswerImages` to keep track of how many images still need to be loaded.
- Add an onload handler for each `<img>` tag that is created so we can keep track of when it's loaded.
- Each time we generate the HTML for an  tag with the onload handler, increment `remainingAnswerImages`.
- When you're done adding all the HTML, check the `remainingAnswerImages` count to see if it's zero (this would only be the case if there were no images or if all images loaded immediately from the browser cache).  If so, call resize() immediately.
- In the onload handler which will be called for each image, decrement `remainingAnswerImages` and if the count has reached zero, call `resize()`.
- While adding images, add one extra to `remainingAnswerImages` as a gate to keep from getting to a zero count until we're done adding images.  When done adding images, take that one extra out.
- I also rewrote the `categoryAnswerLiTag()` function to just create the DOM objects directly rather than concat a bunch of strings together into HTML.  In this case, the code is a lot cleaner to read and maintain.
- I also moved the `$('#categoryQuestionArea #possibleAnswers')` out of your `for` loop since it resolves to the same thing every time.  Better to do it once before the loop.  Also, in most cases, this could be simplified to `$('#possibleAnswers')` since ids are supposed to be unique in the page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jquery plugin that checks the images have loaded: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Sample usage for your case would be:

```
$('#categoryQuestionArea').waitForImages(function() {
   resize();
});
```

I would also just check for the total height of the `<ul>` instead of looping through the list items as you would have to manually change the script if either the padding, margins, or borders on the list items changes later on.

Comment: This is definitely an issue with trying to calculate the height prior to the browser loading the images from the server.  (On the second request, the images are cached.)  The solution is to delay the calculation until after all images have loaded (or even updating it after each image is loaded).

Answer (score 1):

If you do have problems with images on the first page load maybe it is due to the fact that they are not cached and therefore not immediately available. So measuring their height will lead to bad results... did you debug the height that was fetched via jQuery (for example

```
currentHeight = $(this).height();
console.log(currentHeight);
```

The only way to do that is I think to observe the load events of all images (and probably the error as well) and count whether all request have been finished

Comment: Yes, I did debug the current height. On the first page load, the height is often 0. On subsequent page refreshes, the height is correct.

Comment: then it is the fact that the images are not fully requested when you are trying to read their height... since server responses have no static time to finish I doubt you can achieve what you want unless you are using the load / error events of the images

Comment: @FireEmblem - I've offered code in my answer below that keeps track of when all the images are loaded and calls `resize()` when all the heights are valid.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$('img').load(function(){
    //put code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your HTML is screwed up. Particularly, your `<img>` tags.

Add the `width` and `height` attributes to your `<img>` tags. Everything will be magically solved.

See this jsfiddle to understand what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/Vwg7P/

Even though there is no image in there, the `width` and `height` attributes will occupy the space required for the image. As soon as the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a CSS problem, most probably due a fixed height, with items either floated or absolutely positioned.

There are number of ways to fix this.

1. Give a `min-height` instead of fixing a height.

   ```
   #container { min-height: 100px; }
   ```
2. Clear the `float` and do not set any heights

   ```
   #container { overflow: hidden; }
   ```
3. Use Scripts to add up to the height, once every element is added. Like the jQuery snippet below

   ```
   $("#container").append($("#theimg"));
   $("#container").height($("#container").height()+$("#theimg").height());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have a solution for you.

The main idea of my solution lies in CSS. You want to have 3 columns of the same height, right? You can have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/agilius/NvzZp/46/

There is quite a lot of CSS there, but the main idea is this:

1. I simulate a 3 column layout under the actual content, with  the .inner and .column classes.
2. The content is placed over (via z-index 2 > .inner zindex 1), with the same width as the columns that are under.
3. When content is added to the content zones, the height of the main #container updates.
4. Since .inner is top,left,right,bottom = 0, it updates, and since the .columns have 100% height, they update their height to match the #containers height.

Observations.

You can have padding, borders, margins in the .column class as you see fit.

No javascript is required.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple *Equal Height CSS solution:*

**LOGIC** is very simple - 
all of the columns/LI are floated 
with **.eH{ padding-bottom: X; margin-bottom: -X }** and 
wrapper/UL is **.eW{overflow: hidden}**

*X= large arbitrary amount of px for factor of safety*

**EXAMPLE:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/rahen/TXVYD/4/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds exactly like one of the problems i had when coding SudoSlider.

Below i've copied the code i solved it with. Just call `autoheightwidth(i, 0, true)` inside your resize() function.

The basic idea is that you do not know when the browser has completed loading the images, so instead of relying on a single height adjustment, you adjust the height every time something happens (mostly just that an image has been loaded).

It should work if you change the references of "obj" and "li" in the first 2 methods.

It's not very readable, but there was a big focus on size when i coded it.

```
// Automaticly adjust the height and width, i love this function. 
// Before i had one function for adjusting height, and one for width.
function autoheightwidth(i, speed, axis) // Axis: true == height, false == width.
{
    obj.ready(function() {// Not using .load(), because that only triggers when something is loaded.
        adjustHeightWidth (i, speed, axis);
        // Then i run it again after the images has been loaded. (If any)
        // I know everything should be loaded, but just in case. 
        runOnImagesLoaded (li.eq(i), falsev, function(){
            adjustHeightWidth (i, speed, axis);
        });
    });
};
function adjustHeightWidth (i, speed, axis)
{
    var i = getRealPos(i); // I assume that the continuous clones, and the original element is the same height. So i allways adjust acording to the original element.
    var target = li.eq(i);
    // First i run it. In case there are no images to be loaded. 
    var b = target[axis ? "height" : "width"]();
    obj.animate(
        axis ? {height : b} : {width : b},
        {
            queue:falsev,
            duration:speed,
            easing:option[8]/*ease*/
        }
    );
}
function runOnImagesLoaded (target, allSlides, callback) // This function have to be rock stable, cause i use it ALL the time!
{
    var elems = target.add(target.find('img')).filter('img');
    var len = elems.length;
    if (!len)
    {
        callback();
        // No need to do anything else. 
        return this;
    }
    function loadFunction(that)
    {
        $(that).unbind('load').unbind('error');
        // Webkit/Chrome (not sure) fix. 
        if (that.naturalHeight && !that.clientHeight)
        {
            $(that).height(that.naturalHeight).width(that.naturalWidth);
        }
        if (allSlides)
        {
            len--;
            if (len == 0)
            {
                callback();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            callback();
        }
    }
    elems.each(function(){
        var that = this;
        $(that).load(function () {
            loadFunction(that);
        }).error(function () {
            loadFunction(that);
        });
        /*
         * Start ugly working IE fix. 
         */
        if (that.readyState == "complete") 
        {
            $(that).trigger("load");    
        }
        else if (that.readyState)
        {
            // Sometimes IE doesn't fire the readystatechange, even though the readystate has been changed to complete. AARRGHH!! I HATE IE, I HATE IT, I HATE IE!
            that.src = that.src; // Do not ask me why this works, ask the IE team!
        }
        /*
         * End ugly working IE fix. 
         */
        else if (that.complete)
        {
            $(that).trigger("load");
        }
        else if (that.complete === undefined)
        {
            var src = that.src;
            // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
            // data uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
            that.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw=="; // This is about the smallest image you can make. 
            that.src = src;
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the Browser does not know the images' dimensions, because they are not loaded.

Either try to wrap the invocation of `resize` in a

```
jQuery(document).load( function funcName() {
   ...
} )
```

or give the image `width` and `height` attributes in the HTML `img` tags.

Maybe both

Comment: This won't work because the images are dynamically inserted into the page via javascript code.

Comment: Then you should load the image dimensions as well, when inserting the images via JS.